# Cypress. Delete row in table and check it

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have little experience with Java. therefore I ask you for help.
The situation is like this

1. Find out the number of lines
2. Delete line
3. Check that the number of lines is one less than it was

Here is my code. I'm more than sure he's wrong.
And please help me how to write correctly "number of lines - 1" in the last step. Thanks !

````
it('Step 5 - get the table row count', () => {
        cy.getByTestId('user-management-roles-table-container')
            .find("tr")
            .then((row) => {
                //row.length will give you the row count
                cy.log(String(row.length))
            });
    });
    it('Step 6 - Click on the 3 dots', () => {
        cy.getByTestId('button-group-buttonGroup-dropdown-button').first().click();
        cy.getByTestId('select-menu-buttonGroup-items-wrapper').should('be.visible');
    });

    it('Step 7 - Click on the "Delete" button', () => {
        cy.getByTestId('select-menu-buttonGroup-value-delete').click();

    });

    it('Step 8 - ', () => {
        cy.getByTestId('user-management-roles-table-container').find('tr').its('length').should('eq', "number of lines - 1" );
    });
  
    ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
let lenBefore;

it('Step 5 - get the before table row count', () => {
  cy.getByTestId('user-management-roles-table-container').find("tr").its('length').then((len) => {
    lenBefore = len;
    cy.log('Initial table Length is: ' + lenBefore);
  });
});

it('Step 6 - Click on the 3 dots', () => {
  cy.getByTestId('button-group-buttonGroup-dropdown-button').first().click();
  cy.getByTestId('select-menu-buttonGroup-items-wrapper').should('be.visible');
});

it('Step 7 - Click on the "Delete" button', () => {
  cy.getByTestId('select-menu-buttonGroup-value-delete').click();
});

it('Step 5 - get the after table row count', () => {
  cy.getByTestId('user-management-roles-table-container').find("tr").its('length').then((lenAfter) => {
    cy.log('After table Length is: ' + lenAfter);
    expect(lenBefore).to.equal(lenAfter - 1);
  });
});
```

Comment: Alapan Das, many thanks... But, I have an error on the last step

- assert expected 1 to equal 49

error in the "expect(lenBefore).to.equal(lenAfter - 1);"

Please help me to fix it...

Comment: what gets printed in before length and after length ?

Comment: Very sorry !
It's a problem on our server. "delete function" isn't work
But test is a correct
Many many thanks !